# How to add dynamic sum total [Footer] to an array column in laravel excel version 3.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using this reference here > https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html

I use version 3.1 of `Maatwebsite` to map the data and extract it via excel file.

This is my controller function to export the data with.

```
public function exportTestData(Request $request)
{
    $timestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $filename = "act-data-({$timestamp}).xlsx";

    // getActData >> the function of the sql raw query
    return Excel::download(new TestDataExport($this->getActData($request, true)), $filename);
}
```

And it produces this output:

[image: testexport]

**Question:**
How do I add a dynamic data that totals the summary of `Sales`, `Income`, `Both` vertically.

I want a desired output like this:

[image: desiredoutput]

So basically a custom data that totals the summary and add in dynamically after the end of each array. My Total function array assign to cell `H2` totals the data horizontally. How to total each data vertically in this kind of integration. Trying to find any reference to stackoverflow, laracasts, and github but I can't find any good resources to start with.
Can somebody help me with this situation? Thanks.

Here's the full code of my export function to understand the coding process.

**TestDataExport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomStartCell;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;

class TestDataExport implements FromCollection, ShouldAutoSize, WithCustomStartCell, WithHeadings, WithTitle, WithEvents
{
    use Exportable;

    /**
     * testDatas.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $actData;

    public function __construct($testDatas)
    {
        $this->testDatas = $testDatas;
    }

    public function startCell(): string
    {
        return 'A2';
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                /** @var Sheet $sheet */
                $sheet = $event->sheet;

                // map header data to this cells
                $sheet->mergeCells('E1:H1');
                $sheet->setCellValue('E1', "Summaries");

                $styleArray = [
                    'alignment' => [
                        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    ],
                ];

                $cellRange = 'A1:X1'; // All headers center align
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
            },
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        $testDatas = $this->testDatas;

        if (isset($testDatas)) {
            return collect($testDatas)->map(function ($actData, $key) {

                //define totals
                $totals = ! empty($actData['Summaries']) ? $actData['Summaries']['total'] : '0';

                return [
                    'sales' => ! empty($actData['Summaries']) ? $actData['Summaries']['sales'] : '0',
                    'income' => ! empty($actData['Summaries']) ? $actData['Summaries']['income'] : '0',
                    'both' => ! empty($actData['Summaries']) ? $actData['Summaries']['both'] : '0',
                    'total' => ! empty($totals) ? $totals : '0',
                ];
            });
        }

        return collect([]);
    }

    /**
     * Heading of the excel
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Sales',
            'Income',
            'Both',
            'Total',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Title for each sheet
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function title(): string
    {
        return 'Test Data Export';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using this inside my `registerEvents` function.

```
//calculate totals
    
                $sheet->setCellValue('V'. ($sheet->getHighestRow()+1), '=SUM(V3:V'.$sheet->getHighestRow().')');
                $sheet->setCellValue('W'. ($sheet->getHighestRow()+1), '=SUM(W3:W'.$sheet->getHighestRow().')');
                $sheet->setCellValue('X'. ($sheet->getHighestRow()+1), '=SUM(X3:X'.$sheet->getHighestRow().')');
                $sheet->setCellValue('Y'. ($sheet->getHighestRow()+1), '=SUM(Y3:Y'.$sheet->getHighestRow().')');
```

It's giving me the total value of each rows, but I'm also having a problem. Everytime I added a new total to each row. The total will be incremented by 1.

Output here:

[image]

Is there anyway to revamp the code without incrementing it by 1? As of now it will jump from one cell to another

Comment: Did you ever solve this. Documentation is really hard to pick apart and solve.

Comment: yes @warmwhisky, but using hard code one. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this one using the `styles` function

```
public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        $styleArray = [
        'font'  => [
            'bold'  => true,
            'color' => ['rgb' => 'FF0000'],
        ]];

        $sheet->setCellValue('D' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+1), 'TOTALS')->getStyle('D' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);

        // Add cell with SUM formula to last row
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(E2:E' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('E' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('F' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(F2:F' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('F' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('G' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(G2:G' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('G' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('H' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(H2:H' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('H' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('I' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(I2:I' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('I' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('J' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(J2:J' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('J' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('K' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(K2:K' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('K' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('L' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(L2:L' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('L' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('M' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(M2:M' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('M' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('N' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(N2:N' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('N' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('O' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(O2:O' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('O' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('P' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(P2:P' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('P' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('Q' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(Q2:Q' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('Q' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('R' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(R2:R' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('R' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('S' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(S2:S' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('S' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('T' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(T2:T' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('T' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('U' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(U2:U' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('U' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('V' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(V2:V' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('V' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('W' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(W2:W' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('W' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('X' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(X2:X' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('X' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('Y' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(Y2:Y' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('Y' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('Z' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(Z2:Z' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('Z' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('AA' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(AA2:AA' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('AA' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('AB' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(AB2:AB' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('AB' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
        $sheet->setCellValue('AC' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()+0), '=SUM(AC2:AC' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()-1) . ')')->getStyle('AC' . ($sheet->getHighestRow()))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    }
```

In the first CellValue which is `D` this one will increment the last data and add it just right below to compute the totals.

For the following `E` > `AC` when I try to use `$sheet->getHighestRow()+1)` for each `setCellValue` the data is incremented after every cell column. I tried experimenting it but it seems when you add `$sheet->getHighestRow()+0)` on cell `E` > `AC` it will be then placed the totals of each column. Don't know why, maybe some of you can find and alternative or a better way for this one.